# My motion tracking trembles in the end of footage. Did I do something wrong? Or do I need to replace the camera?

Tags: tracking

It's seventh try. Tracking of full sized footage took too long, so I've downscaled it. I've used the Autotrack plugin. The tracker settings are default, except for model set to Perspective. And for plugin, distance set to 60 and frame separation to 1. Camera settings set to 24mm in 35mm equivalent, then preset for my size of camera. Keyframe A is 60 and B is 90. Using Clean Tracks I've managed to set the tracking error to about 0.4. I've noticed that in place where the camera trembles, markers on the ground die quickly.

[Here's archive with the tracked footage.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1O2IVzm6Yl6eUpHSE5mMGFueXM)

Comment: Please read through the following link with suggestions on how to get better results with motion tracking; https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking/42332#42332

Comment: Yes I have shaky footage, and no markers. But tiny markers are invisible to camera, and after downscaling they should disappear completely. Well, if I have big enough markers I won't need to downscale, but then camera will be very sensitive to shaking. Currently it's eighth try with solve error 0.3196. Possibly can't be better.